# using a button to navigate to different view in navigation based application?

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

i created a navigation based project but instead of tableview i added a new view with a button to navigate to the other view.. my button code is as shown below but whenever i run it the application doesn't run?? is the code wrong or navigation based application only work with tableview??

```
-(IBAction)clickMe:(id)sender

chdDetails *details=[[chdDetails dalloc]initWithNibName:@"chdDetails" bundle:nil];  
[self.navigationController pushViewController:details animated:YES];    
[details release];
details=nil;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says "[[chdDetails **dalloc**]initW.... instead of *alloc*. is that a copy-waste typo?

No a navigationCOntroller will work with any viewController, you don't even need the navigationbar. I bet most application are navigationBased but you don't even see it.

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES]
```

Will do that.

Try placing a breakpoint in the `clickMe` method to test if it even gets called. What does this mean:  *"the application doesn't run??"* is there an error message? Have you hooked the button up in IB? Is chdDetails a subclass of UIViewController? etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

Is chdDetails an UIViewController or an UIView? You can't push an UIView on an UINavigationController, only controllers.